# Can I parse a dataframe by row number?

Tags: pandas

I'm not sure if this is possible but say I have this:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2),index=range(0,10,2),columns=list('AB'))

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
          A         B
0  1.068932 -0.794307
2 -0.470056  1.192211
4 -0.284561  0.756029
6  1.037563 -0.267820
8 -0.538478 -0.800654

In [5]: df.iloc[[2]]
Out[5]: 
          A         B
4 -0.284561  0.756029
```

I know how to select a specific row(2 in above example) but say I want to create a new dataframe from above using 2 and beyond:

```
4 -0.284561  0.756029
6  1.037563 -0.267820
8 -0.538478 -0.800654
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your answer you could change the iloc to have a : wildcard

```
df2 = df.iloc[1:]
```

This would let you look at everything 2+ in the index

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2),index=range(0,10,2),columns=list('AB'))
df.iloc[2:]
```

[image]